# Local git repos are not being recognized by git-bash a re-installing windows 10 while new repos are working fine

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository, local, git-bash

I am new to git. I was using git bash recently re installd windows 10 into my laptop. But all my local repos which I was using easily using git bash are giving this error (fatal error unsafe repository ('/home/repo' is owned by someone else). which is coz its not able to find .git folder I guess.
And if try to do new repo in my local via git bash that is working fine but my old repos are not working.[git bash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9alh.png)
[vscode for same dir.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il2dT.png)

I tried to re-install git and config'd my credentials but not worked. I need to access my old repos as previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reinstalled win10, you are now technically using a different user account (i.e. user account SID is different).

And, for security reasons, since git 2.35.2 git does a check if the repository file owner is the same than the current user and prevent using it if different.

**So you have to change the files owner and rights in the file explorer to be the current user. The best option if you can!**
Or you have to add a security exception for each old repository (it's a workaround not the real good solution in your case).

See the [doc for adding an exception](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.35.2#Documentation/git-config.txt-safedirectory)

The command is the following (if you decide to go this way):

```
 git config --global --add safe.directory <path to repository>
```

See also [the security announcement](https://github.blog/2022-04-12-git-security-vulnerability-announced/) where the command is advertised...

Comment: yeah it worked like awesome tnx bro